# Generic Module Routing in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

We are using ZF2 for a website project that has two modules, frontend and backend.  We would like to generate URLs for both of those modules that have the following canonical form:

`/module/controller/action`

So far we tried this solution and we have not been able to make it work

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/[:module[/:controller[/:action]]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'module'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*', 
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'module'     => 'Front',
                    'controller' => 'Front\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
),
```

We would like the URL to look like `/modulename/controllername` without the need to create specific routes for each module similar to the old default route for ZF1.  Is it possible to do that or is there a way specific to zf2?

Comment: Hi @exfrom-theleft, did you manage to get this functionality? If yes, then how? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new ZF2 Beta5, there is a new listener Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener, so you would have to add a **__*NAMESPACE*__** key to your route, this will prepend the namespace to the Controller, and thus, you will have a generic route.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We have tried this solution, but this works only if the module routing is static. In our case, we would like to have a dynamic routing of our modules (Front & Back) in the default module (Application).